# Grep to filter gigantic CSV file

Tags: bash, grep, csv

I'm dealing with a CSV file that contains over 2 million lines. Quite a big one.

I need to use grep (or any better way) to retrieve the entire row if the value of the second column matches 'jpn' or 'por'.

I tried using `grep '<\jpn\>' || grep '<\por\>' file1.csv > file2.csv` but had no success so far. The major issue being that 'por' is a common occurrence on the third column, which generates over a million of undesired rows.

Would any more experienced user be se kind and lend me some help?

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What Linux OS are you on? Try using `egrep` if you want to use regular expressions in systems whose grep version is outdated (e.g. Solaris).

Anyway, here is an awk solution:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /jpn|por/ {print}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Explanations:

- `awk` for column-based operations
- `-F,` to define the column separator/tokenizer, in this case I use a comma
- `$2 ~ /jpn|por/` tests column #2 with expression `/jpn|por/`

  - `$2` is column #2
  - `/jpn|por/` is a regular expression to match jpn or por
- **`{`**`print`**`}`** specifies what the awk should output if it found a matching line

  - `print` to print the whole input line (alternatively, `print $3` will just print column #3)
- `... file1.csv` specifies to read from an input file instead of stdin

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.10. - Your tip worked like a charm! Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: Old question I know but, I was trying to filter my csv on those where the column 32 is `TX`: `awk -F, '$32 ~ /TX/ {print}' input.csv > TEXAS_ONLY.csv`. It *mostly* worked, yet a few don't make sense. I'm looking at one for example that's in `AZ` ...

Comment: @nute If it works on some lines, my guess is the data might be not clean. Try checking at the lines that does not make sense, and the lines above and below that line: whether there is an extra comma/separator in the data, and whether there are extra line-breaks or any non-printable characters in the data.

Comment: @aff this is awesome ! thanks for a detailed answer. If I want to use a regex expression to say "starts with jpn" and add two columns, can I do `awk -F, '$1 ~ /^jpn|^por/ && $2 ~ /^jpn|^por/ {print}' file1.csv > file2.csv` ?

Comment: @vagabond That expression will tell awk to print the lines if column 1 and column 2 *both* starts with *either* 'jpn' or 'por', if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`grep '; jpn;\|; por;' /path/to/file1.csv > file2.csv`

Assuming that semicolon (;) is the separator.

Answer (score 1):

I think `grep` is a limited solution for this problem, because it wouldn't consider different separators and escaped separators.

I'd suggest you check out [TextQ](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/textq/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It can import a big CSV file and allows you to manage its schema/structure.

You can perform queries via a UI Query Builder or via SQL (select, join, group by, etc).

Here is a [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ozIZPuQF8&t=11s) and [more detailed tutorial](https://medium.com/@geo.systems.developer/textq-analysing-and-filtering-huge-csv-files-4a45561613bb).

Finally, you can export any query to a CSV file, which can be imported in MS Excel or others.
You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/textq/id1571423170) or Microsoft Store (soon).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe this could work:

```
grep '^[^,]*,\(por\|jpn\)\(,\|$\)' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Assuming that "," is the separator.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
egrep '^.?,(jpn|por),.*$' file1.csv > file2.csv
```